# p5.js and an odd result

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to draw an image using characters without having the original image in the background.

I know that removing an image after drawing on top of it isn't easy on P5, so I have tried several different ways. The issue I've just come across is the text color is a bit off in comparison to the actual image.

Beneath is the code, original photo, result, and some of the other methods ive tried! :

**Solved!**
The issue was fixed by replacing get with img.get as well as correcting the x and y if statement to allow for spacing between the text values. Thank you for all your help!

Original Image
[image: The 'input']

An example of the desired output
[![The desired output][3]][3]

The Output after correcting pixels to img.pixels
[![The changed output][4]][4]

Updated Code:

```
img = null;
width = 0;
height = 0;
nX = 0;
nY = 0;
textSize = 20; 
color = (0,0,0);
var colors = [];
timer = 0;

function preload(){
    img = loadImage("input.jpg");
    img.loadPixels();
    width = img.width;
    height = img.height;
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
}

function draw() {
    image(img, 0, 0);
    img.loadPixels();
    textSize(16);
    noiseDetail(0.1);

    for(y = 0; y <= img.height; y++){
        for(x = 0; x <= img.width; x++){
            nX = noise(x);
            nY = noise(y);
            if(x%20==0&&y%20==0){
                color = img.get(x,y);
                fill(color);
                text(color[0],nX+x,nY+y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Methods I have tried:

- Iterate through and add to an array but came across another error
- Simply writing over the image but the background image still has a strong presence
- Array of the values for color, x, and y for each value, clearing and then trying to grab those values unsuccessfully but when I did that the values past the second half of the picture, from top right to bottom left corner, were black despite not being black in the image.

*Many thanks to those whose have helped edit this post.*

Comment: This is rather unclear.  We need to see an example of the desired outcome to understand what you are trying to achieve.  It's not clear what you mean by _"draw an image using text to be able to draw the image rather than the image itself"_, and _"remove an image isnt easy"_. Also, please [edit] your question to see the formatting changes I made, and click the help link in the editor to get help on how to use Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop drawing your image to the screen.

Instead of using the `pixels` array to get the color of the screen, use `img.pixels` to refer directly to the color of the image. This way you don't have to draw your image to the screen.

Comment: I managed to swap pixels and img.pixels and got this as a result. https://imgur.com/rwiXYa5

Comment: @ThomasHartley It might not be as simple as swapping one line. You'll have to take a step back and look at your approach as a whole. I'm saying that you can go to the image directly instead of the screen to get the pixel color, but you might have to change more than one line to get that to work perfectly. Also what are you doing with the `noise()` function, and why are you using `color` as an array? Try to get something simple working first.